# Diffeomorphic surfaces and Jacobian

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are bounded (open) surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let them have boundary $\partial S$ and $\partial T$.

Suppose $F:S \to T$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism.

Under what conditions on $F$ and $S$ and $T$ and their boundaries do we get that the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $F$ is bounded above and below by positive numbers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean your surfaces to be the interior of compact manifolds with boundary (as your question seems to imply) then the existence of bounds is immediate from the compactness of the boundary, so long as $k$ is at least $1$.

If you don't assume from the start that the map extends to a diffeomorphism of the boundary, then the claim is not true, as can be seen already in the 1-dimensional case.  Thus, the self-map of the interval $[0,1]$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$ is a diffeomorphism of the interior, but the Jacobian on the boundary is singular.

To make sure the map extends to the boundary, one would impose a suitable condition of uniform convergence (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence for the case of sequences).  To get $C^k$ one would need such bounds for the $k$-th derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, which comment is that? I am not really familiar with manifolds in this sense. But I am guessing that the diffeomorphism can be extended to the closure of $S$ and $T$ and $C^1$ obviously will suffice in that case

Comment: @user72694 Sorry, why is that map not a diffeomorphism on the whole of $[0,1]$?

Comment: It is certainly a self-homeomorphism of the closed interval, but since the derivative vanishes at $0$ you can't say that "the Jacobian is bounded below by a positive number".  One can construct similar examples in the 2-dimensional case where the map does not even extend to the boundary.